# Xamarin.iOS:Layer.InsertSublayer is not working in iOS 14.1 as it was previously working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, calayer, ios14

In my app I am adding gradiant layer on  the cell on some condition. In previous versions of iOS it worked fine, but after updating to 14.1 it stopped showing gradiant.
Following is the code which is used to show gradiant.

```
Layer.InsertSublayer(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), 0);
```

I have tested it on iOS 11 simulator and this code works fine, but for iOS 14 it don't shown on cell. When I change the index from 0 to 1 (as shown below),

```
Layer.InsertSublayer(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), 1);
```

the gradiant get shown on iOS 14 device but on iOS-11 device, gradiant layer show in from of the text and the text of the cell get back to this gradiant layer and don't shown  (Please note that Layer is  a CALayer's object).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the describtion, you could use following ways to solve whether belong to iOS 14 device first:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
{
    Layer.InsertSublayer(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), 1);
}
else
{
    Layer.InsertSublayer(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), 0);
}
```

About the reason, I guess that in iOS 14 device there should be more than one sub-layer, therefore, inset at `0` can not show.

You also could have a try with following ways to check whether can work:

```
if(Layer.Sublayers.Length > 1)
{
    Layer.InsertSublayer(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), 1);
    // or try this
    Layer.InsertSublayerAbove(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), Layer.Sublayers[0]);
}
else
{
    Layer.InsertSublayer(Utility.GetGradientLayer(Frame, GradientColor.Green), 0);
}
```

Comment: thankyou dear, but i was expacting some detailed reply, if there is any change in new ios version. I am already using the above solution that you mentioned but i am not satisfied with that, so posted the question to know about the main reason that what causes the workinng code broken. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user6159419 Thanks for marking, I also vote up your answer. If find a detailed reason, 
I will update here later.

Answer (score 1):

Junior Jiang posted a good solution but I found another pretty simple hack. Instead of change in code, we only need to make transparent background of the cell. So if gradiant is any number of layer it will be shown straight forward. There will be no need to impose any os related or layer related checks.
If anyone else found better solution then please let us know. Regards